# Nativescript vue login function return true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

Hello I'm using a function very similar to this one, with little changes https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=HdDm9M&v=786

When I login to my rest api, if I put in the wrong username or password, it always returns true (by logging me in).

It should execute the `catch` block when my username or password is wrong but it does not do that. I had this issue before and fixed it but now I can't figure out why this happens.

In my Login.vue

```
     login() {
            this.$backend
                .login(this.user)
                .then(() => {

                    // if login success then save login and password in local storage
                    appSettings.setString("username", this.user.username);
                    appSettings.setString("password", this.user.password);


                    this.$store.commit('setActualPage', 'Main');
                    this.processing = false;
                    this.$navigateTo(Main, { clearHistory: true });

                })
                .catch(() => {
                    this.processing = false;
                    this.alert(
                    "Username or password are not correct."
                    );
                });
        },
```

and my backend-service.js

```
  login(user) {

    return httpModule.request({
        url: "MYRESTAPIURL",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "username": user.username,
            "password": user.password,
            "apikey": "814973593645gg6db8ca6983789f"
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        let result = response.content.toJSON();


        return result;

        //console.log(result.premiumdays)
    }, (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

This `return result;` gives the output below if it's the wrong user or password:

```
{ error: 'Not connected.' }
```

Even if I put `return;` to return `false` it logs me in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your code : when your back-end service login failed,the result JSON is send back to your page(login.vue),so maybe you should add some code to verify  the return JSON:

**login.vue**:

```
login() {
            this.$backend
                .login(this.user)
                .then((resp) => {

                   // verify the return data
                   if(resp && resp.error){
                       // login failed,do sth
                        this.processing = false;
                        this.alert(
                           "Username or password are not correct."
                        );
                   }else{
                        // login success
                   }

                })
                .catch(() => {
                    this.processing = false;
                    this.alert(
                    "Username or password are not correct."
                    );
                });
        },
```

the `catch` statement will not be executed unless the HTTP response code is not `200`.so the `login failed` **is not an error request,it is just an succeed request with the error data**

Comment: lol u was right but it workes 2 times and now catch is fire up. I tried postman whats going on and if I send the same post request with valid usernam, password, apikey, it returns code 200 and "no body returned for response" . before it was returning data from mysql database for particular user. do you know what is happen?

Comment: your back-end service is an `async` call to `httpModule.request`,your **return statement** is in the `then` callback function,but your  `login` function maybe return undefined `before` the `then` callback. so you should return a Promise in `login` function and `resolve` it in the `then` callback